# custom bottomActionsBuilder for taking picture in camerawesome flutter

Tags: flutter, package, camera, android-camera

I'm using the camera awesome package to be able to open the phone's camera in my app and be able to switch between photo and video on the camera. But I wanted to change the bottom of the buttons.

[In the standard UI of the package, when you click to take a capture, the photo appears where I point in the image. In my code, when I click on the image, a showDialog appears to check the image in a larger size and the user can choose whether to take a photo again or add the one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k100W.png)

I would like to change this so that when I click on the middle button, this function can be executed, but the package is a little complicated to use.